# How to show $g(0) = g(1)$ here

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the last part of this statement: If $f: [0,1]\to [-\infty, \infty]$ is an integrable function, then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and a set $A$ such that $\mu(A)<\varepsilon$ and $|f(x) - g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\notin A$, and $g(0)=g(1)$.

I was able to prove the first part. I have a feeling that the second part comes from the fact that continuous functions are approximated by step functions, but can't quite see how to make it rigorous, nor how to visualize it. Thoughts?

Comment: The way to think about it is that you shouldn't care of what happens in A. So you could define g to be whatever you want in a point which has a zero measure. Hope that helpful

Comment: Okay, so I could just change the values at the endpoints to be the same and still approximate $g$ really well with step functions, as they will differ only on a finite set, which is a null set? Is that the idea?

Comment: Yes that's the idea the connection to the original function will be in a set as small as you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for $0<\varepsilon<1$ you have a continuous function $g_{\varepsilon}$, with $A_{\varepsilon}$, satisfying all your conditions, but you have not $g_{\varepsilon}(0)=g_{\varepsilon}(1)$. Then you can define a new continuous function $h_{\varepsilon}$ in the following way: on $[0,1-\varepsilon]$, take $h_{\varepsilon}=g_{\varepsilon}$; on $[1-\varepsilon,1]$, $h_{\varepsilon}(x)=ax+b$ with $a(1-\varepsilon)+b=g_{\varepsilon}(1-\varepsilon)$, and $a+b=g_{\varepsilon}(0)$. Then with $A^{\prime}=A_{\varepsilon}\cup [1-\varepsilon,1]$, you are done (for $2\varepsilon$, but this is not a problem).

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: @Hugh Mungus You are welcome.